# JavaScript If/Else Function For Input Slider

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a an input slider which uses css translate for both "-" and "+" values using a JavaScript if/else function. I'm having a little problem with the if/else statement though.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cn6St/ and here's the code:

HTML

```
 <div class="square"></div>

 <span class="result-X">Transform-X:</span>

 <input type="range" id="sliderX" min="0" max="100" value="50" onchange="rangevalueX.value=value"/>

 <output id="rangevalueX">50</output>
```

JS:

```
var sliderx = document.getElementById("sliderX");
var box = document.querySelector('.square');
var rangevalueX = document.getElementById("rangevalueX");

sliderx.onchange = function(){

    if (rangevalueX >'50') {
    box.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + (sliderx.value) + 'px)';
    rangevalueX.value = sliderx.value;
    }
    else if (rangevalueX <'50') {
    box.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(-" + (sliderx.value) + 'px)';
    rangevalueX.value = sliderx.value;
    }
    };
```

The idea is to use the value of "50" on the slider as "0" in terms of translate. If the slider value is > 50 the CSS should transform a positive value. If it's less <50 it should be negative.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here through.

Comment: Can't you have HTML? `<input type="range" id="sliderX" min="-50" max="50" value="0" onchange="rangevalueX.value=value"/>`

Comment: Yes. That's what I've tried. See my answer below. It seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do:

```
var rangevalueX = document.getElementById('rangevalueX').value;
```

To get the actual slider value.

Answer (score 0):

I Seem to have found the issue. It was the HMTL. The value of the slider should be set to "0", while the `min should be "-50" and the max value should be "50".`

Final working code:

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="square"></div>

    <div>
       <span class="result-X">Transform-X:</span>
        <input type="range" id="sliderX" min="-50" max="50" value="0" onchange="rangevalueX.value=value"/>
        <output id="rangevalueX">0</output>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var sliderx = document.getElementById("sliderX");
var box = document.querySelector('.square');
var rangevalueX = document.getElementById("rangevalueX");

sliderx.onchange = function(){

    if (rangevalueX >'50') {
    box.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + (sliderx.value) + 'px)';
    rangevalueX.value = sliderx.value;
    }
    else if (rangevalueX <'50') {
    box.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(-" + (sliderx.value) + 'px)';
    rangevalueX.value = sliderx.value;
    }
    };
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cn6St/2/